# flex arraycollection advancedDatagrid

Tags: apache-flex, adobe

if i have two set of arraycollection like:

var abc:arraycollection = new arraycollection([{region:"AAA"}])

var cde:arraycollection = new arraycollection([{territory:"A"},{territory:"b"}])

how do i palm the above two set of arraycollection to advancedDatagrid

thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you try to be a bit more precise ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question: 
try to make a third arraycollection out of these two to suite your data for advancedDatagrid, and add is as dataprovider.

Comment: i have two arraycollection and wanna display in advanceddatagrid. is it possible.

Comment: can you merge them in one arraycollection ?

Comment: because i have follow Clear data builder tutorial. how do i put the company and company associate into advancedDatagrid. thanks